# npm run build not adding Spring Boot context path

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-boot, war

I have a Spring Boot backend and ReactJS front end, all builds and runs fine until I deploy to a tomcat external server.

In the index.html page which gets generated via the npm run build it is creating paths as below (this is part of index.html):

```
<script src="/static/js/2.507eac03.chunk.js"></script>
```

So, when the index.html is loaded, it cannot locate /static/js/2.507eac03.chunk.js because it is missing my application context folder (where my webapp is) - is this something in Spring boot I need to do in order for it to work?

PS. Removing the / makes it work as it then picks up my application context folder:

```
<script src="static/js/2.507eac03.chunk.js"></script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is a neat and simple HTML solution for your problem:

```
<base href="/your/context/location" target="_blank">
```

If the tag above is in your `head`, then you can refer to locations in the manner you desire.

Comment: Thanks for that but still doesn't work...This line still doesn't pick up the base url due to the slash at the start of it:  <script src="/static/js/main.a6b80684.chunk.js"></script> and I cannot just remove the slash as this is built via npm run build.

Comment: @SteveGreen npm run build is running on the server-side. I do not really understand what prevents you from rendering a `base` tag in your HTML. That will be evaluated in your browser. I might be missing something, of course.